# Why listener in hibernate.cfg.xml not called?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Why the listener in hibernate.cfg.xml not called?

What are the possible reason for this? This is a Tomcat app.

I am sure I have a class called xxx.NotificationEventListener

```
<event type="post-insert">
<listener class="xxx.NotificationEventListener" />
</event>
```

...

Comment: There are insert actions, but event not fired

Comment: Maybe you can try setting a breakpoint on AuditEventListener to see if the listener is invoked?

Comment: What is AuditEventListener ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the project has upgraded to Hibernate 4, which no longer handles the `<event>` elements.